# sample HTML to test javascript codes

Tags: javascript

I have just started learning Javascript and Ok here is a code I want to try and see it in the browser, so I create a test.js file and put this in it:

```
function useless(callback) {
    return callback
}

var text = 'Amigo';

assert(
    useless(function(){ return text; }) === text,
    "The useless function works! " + text);
```

But still there is more, I should write a minimum HTML page than can call this function, What is sample HTML to host this method in it?

I have written something like this but still there is something wrong with it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="hehe.js" >
    useless('Amigo');
    window.onload=useless('Amigo')
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So the book you're reading doesn't teach you how to incorporate js to a page and call functions?

Comment: @zerkms : No it doesn't have the HTML part...realign form Javascript Ninja book

Comment: "I have written something like this" --- where did you see that syntax? Just put something random and expected it to work?

Comment: Take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="hehe.js"></script>
<script  >
    useless('Amigo');
    window.onload=useless('Amigo')
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can load the source in a separate script from the inline one that you call it in.  Note that this assumes that hehe.js is in the root directory of your site.

For testing js in general [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a nice resource that lets you define your html/js/css and experiment with small changes without having to write out all the files.

Comment: thanks but that still didn't show anything on the browser. Actually for the assert function I have used in the JS part, the IDE is saying "unresolved symbol"

Comment: Assert is not a built in JS function.